# Remove text between delimiters in linux

Tags: shell, perl, text

Server got hacked and a fair amount of files were edited. We noticed that the code that was inserted were typically done between delimiters (e.g. `/*e21234*/ blah blah /*/e21234*/`). What is the most efficient way to remove this from a large number of files on a linux box? (I tried using sed but couldn't quite get it. I'm open to using perl or whatever would work)

Comment: [The easiest, and best way (by far) is to format the server and restore from backups.](http://serverfault.com/q/218005/118258)  Only way to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
sed 's,/\*e21234\*/.*e21234\*/,,g'
```

But I agree that restoring a backup is probably best!

Comment: This won't handle stuff spanning lines (in sed, '.' doesn't match newline). Perhaps `sed -r -e 's,/\*e2134\*/(.|\n)*/.*e21234\*/,,g'` helps. In any case, you won't ever be sure you got rid of all of it.